# Numerical methods - iteration equations

Tags: numerical-methods

(a) show that $e^x - x = 4$ has a root between $1$ and $2$ (fine with this part)

(b) show that the iterative formula

$x_{n+1} = {e^{x_n}(x_n - 1) + 4 \over e^{x_n} -1}$

Leads to a solution of the equation in part (a)

Are you supposed to re arrange the first equation because I am unable to see how I can get the second equation?

Comment: consider the function $f(x)=e^x-x-4$ and use calculus

Comment: The itterative formula comes about from applying [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method) $x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$ to find the root of the function $f(x) = e^x-x-4$

Answer (score 1):

This is just the formula corresponding to Newton method.

Suppose that you approximate, around $x=a$, a function $f(x)$ using Taylor series. So $$f(x)=f(a)+(x-a) f'(a)+O\left((x-a)^2\right)$$ Ignore the high order terms $[$at this point you can notice that what we wrote is the equation of the tangent to the curve at point $(a,f(a))$, this illustratic the geometric approach of the method $]$, then $$f(x)=0\implies f(a)+(x-a) f'(a)=0\implies x= a-\frac{f(a)}{f'(a)}$$ So, replace $a$ by this new $x$ and repeat; let start using $x_0=a$ and repeat the process to get the classical $$x_{n+1}= x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$

Comment: In part (c) I have found the root of the equation to 6dp (1.749031). Part (d) then asks to find the root of e^2cosx - 2cosx - 4 = 0, which I am unsure of how to approach

Comment: a small change of variable transforms this equation to the previous one

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = e^x-x-4$, we are looking for zeros of $f$.

Note that the update formula $\phi(x) = {e^x(x-1)+4 \over e^x -1} = x - { f(x) \over f'(x)}$ is only
defined for $x \neq 0$, hence the statement in (b) is not strictly correct
(the iteration is not defined if one starts at $x_0=0$).

However, if $x_0 < 0$ then $x_n$ will converge to the root in $[-4,-2]$
and if $x_0 >0$ then $x_n$ will converge to the root in $[1,2]$.

Note that $f$ is strictly convex with $f'(0) = 0$, hence $f'(x) >0$ for $x >0$
and $f'(0) < 0$ for $x<0$. Since $\lim_{|x|\to \infty} f(x) = + \infty$ and
$f(0) < 0$ it follows that there are exactly two roots, one in
$(-\infty,0)$ and one in $(0, \infty)$.

Since $f$ is convex, we have $f(y)-f(x) \ge f'(x) (y-x)$ for all $x,y$.

The analysis for $x>0$ and $x<0$ are similar, I will deal with $x>0$ here.
Note that if $x_{n+1} = \phi(x_n)$ then $f(x_n) + f'(x_n) (x_{n+1}-x_n) = 0$.
Hence $f(x_{n+1}) \ge f(x_n) + f'(x_n) (x_{n+1}-x_n) = 0$.

Suppose $x_n >0$ and let $x^*$ be the unique zero in $(0,\infty)$. Then
$f(x) <0$ for $x \in (0,x^*) $ and $f(x)>0$ for $x \in (x^* , \infty)$.

Since $f(x_{n+1}) \ge 0$, we have $x_n \ge x^*$ for all $n >1$.

If $x_n \ge x^*$, then since $x_{n+1}-x_n = - {f(x_n) \over f'(x_n) }$,
we see that $x_{n+1} \le x_n$ and hence $x^* \le x_{n+1} \le x_n$.

Hence, for $n>1$ the sequence $x_n$ is monotonic and decreasing, hence
$x_n \to \tilde{x}$ for some $\tilde{x}$. Since $x^* \le \tilde{x}$, we have
$f'(\tilde{x}) >0$ and so $f(\tilde{x}) = 0$ (since $\phi(\tilde{x}) = \tilde{x}$) and hence $\tilde{x} = x^*$.
That is, $x_n \to x^*$.

In fact, it is not too difficult to establish that $x_n$ converges to $x^*$ 
very quickly (quadratic) if $x_0$ is close enough to $x^*$.